# How do you find the disk size of a Postgres / PostgreSQL table and its indexes

Tags: postgresql

I'm coming to Postgres from Oracle and looking for a way to find the table and index size in terms of `bytes/MB/GB/etc`, or even better the size for all tables.  In Oracle I had a nasty long query that looked at user_lobs and user_segments to give back an answer.

I assume in Postgres there's something I can use in the `information_schema` tables, but I'm not seeing where.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage

Answer (score 413, accepted):

Try the [Database Object Size Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE). An example:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"<schema>"."<table>"'));
```

For all tables, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    table_schema || '.' || table_name AS table_full_name,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"')) AS size
FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY
    pg_total_relation_size('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') DESC;
```

Edit: Here's the query submitted by @phord, for convenience:

```
SELECT
    table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(table_size) AS table_size,
    pg_size_pretty(indexes_size) AS indexes_size,
    pg_size_pretty(total_size) AS total_size
FROM (
    SELECT
        table_name,
        pg_table_size(table_name) AS table_size,
        pg_indexes_size(table_name) AS indexes_size,
        pg_total_relation_size(table_name) AS total_size
    FROM (
        SELECT ('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') AS table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
    ) AS all_tables
    ORDER BY total_size DESC
) AS pretty_sizes;
```

I've modified it slightly to use `pg_table_size()` to include metadata and make the sizes add up.

Comment: Incidentally, if someone has any information on how to alias the big, repeated expression, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: You can't alias it, but you can always run it in a subquery... like:
SELECT table_full_name,pg_size_pretty(size) FROM (
   SELECT .. AS table_full_name, .. AS size FROM ....
) x 
ORDER BY size

Comment: A suggestion: change `'"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"'` to `format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name)`.

Comment: Skip the `pg_size_pretty` and just do the inner query if you want raw byte counts to be processed programmatically, such as for your own javascript dashboard.

Comment: Another suggestion: change `'"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"'` to `table_schema.table_name` - PostgreSQL only requires indentifier quoting if there are spaces, caplitalisation or punctuation! Stick to snake_case with characters and digits (digit can't, IIRC, be the first character of an identifer) - with 63 characters `you_can_have_quite_a_long_idenfier_name_with_no_problems_at_all` (63 chars!).

Answer (score 217):

Show database sizes:

`\l+`

e.g.

```
=> \l+
 berbatik_prd_commerce    | berbatik_prd     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 19 MB   | pg_default | 
 berbatik_stg_commerce    | berbatik_stg     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 8633 kB | pg_default | 
 bursasajadah_prd         | bursasajadah_prd | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 1122 MB | pg_default |
```

Show table sizes:

`\d+`

e.g.

```
=> \d+
 public | tuneeca_prd | table | tomcat | 8192 bytes | 
 public | tuneeca_stg | table | tomcat | 1464 kB    |
```

Only works in `psql`.

(Summary of [@zkutch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13743224/122441).)

Comment: If one needs to see both tables and indexes, `\dti+` will do the trick.

Comment: This returns sorted by name though, the top answer returns sorted by size descending

Answer (score 27):

If the database name is `snort`, the following sentence give its size:

```
psql -c "\l+ snort" | awk -F "|" '{print $7}'
```

Comment: By far the simplest answer for a quick view of size. I have put this in a shell function ``dbsize``.

Comment: Also, you can add `-t` to `psql` command to avoid column title in the output (which can be useful for automation), e.g.: `psql -c "\l+ snort" -t | awk -F "|" '{print $7}'`

Answer (score 24):

Try this : (Index size/usage statistics)

```
SELECT
    t.tablename,
    indexname,
    c.reltuples AS num_rows,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(t.tablename)::text)) AS table_size,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(indexrelname)::text)) AS index_size,
    CASE WHEN indisunique THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
    END AS UNIQUE,
    idx_scan AS number_of_scans,
    idx_tup_read AS tuples_read,
    idx_tup_fetch AS tuples_fetched
FROM pg_tables t
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_class c ON t.tablename=c.relname
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( SELECT c.relname AS ctablename, ipg.relname AS indexname, x.indnatts AS number_of_columns, idx_scan, idx_tup_read, idx_tup_fetch, indexrelname, indisunique FROM pg_index x
           JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = x.indrelid
           JOIN pg_class ipg ON ipg.oid = x.indexrelid
           JOIN pg_stat_all_indexes psai ON x.indexrelid = psai.indexrelid )
    AS foo
    ON t.tablename = foo.ctablename
WHERE t.schemaname='public'
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Answer (score 12):

PostgreSQL tables have three components:  the table itself, any indexes on it, and potentially TOAST data.  There's a couple of examples showing how to slice and dice the available information various ways at http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage

Answer (score 8):

Just for info, I have got the excelent answer from @aib and modified it a little for:

- getting only tables from "public" schema
- show also **materialized views** data and index size

On materialized view we can use index for [refreshing materialized views concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803781/refresh-materialized-views-with-concurrency), which allows using them while updating.

Well,  my query will be the following:

```
SELECT
    table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(table_size) AS table_size,
    pg_size_pretty(indexes_size) AS indexes_size,
    pg_size_pretty(total_size) AS total_size
FROM (
    SELECT
        table_name,
        pg_table_size(table_name) AS table_size,
        pg_indexes_size(table_name) AS indexes_size,
        pg_total_relation_size(table_name) AS total_size
    FROM (
        -- tables from 'public'
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        where table_schema = 'public' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        union
        -- materialized views
        SELECT oid::regclass::text as table_name
        FROM pg_class
        WHERE relkind = 'm'
        order by table_name
    ) AS all_tables
    -- ORDER BY total_size DESC
    order by table_name
) AS pretty_sizes
```

Comment: I think in the `-- tables from 'public'` subquery, the `table_name` needs to be cast to text. After making that change, the query worked for me. Without it, I get a generic type error on the `pg_table_size` function. `table_name` is of type `information_schema.sql_identifier`

Answer (score 1):

check this wiki. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage

```
SELECT *, pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
    , pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX
    , pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
    , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE
  FROM (
  SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-COALESCE(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes FROM (
      SELECT c.oid,nspname AS table_schema, relname AS TABLE_NAME
              , c.reltuples AS row_estimate
              , pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
              , pg_indexes_size(c.oid) AS index_bytes
              , pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_bytes
          FROM pg_class c
          LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
          WHERE relkind = 'r'
  ) a
) a
```

Answer (score 1):

The Query below will serve you

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "total_size"
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  AND C.relkind <> 'i'
  AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

See this Link: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage

Answer (score 0):

A running percent of table size :

```
WITH 
T AS
(
SELECT table_schema, table_name, 
       pg_total_relation_size('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS TABLE_SIZE_MB,
       SUM(pg_total_relation_size('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"')) OVER() / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS TOTAL_TABLE_SIZE_MB,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"'), table_schema, table_name) AS N
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
)
SELECT table_schema, table_name, CAST(TABLE_SIZE_MB AS DECIMAL(16, 2)) AS TABLE_SIZE_MB,
       CAST(TOTAL_TABLE_SIZE_MB AS DECIMAL(16, 2))  AS TOTAL_TABLE_SIZE_MB,
       CAST(100.0 * TABLE_SIZE_MB / TOTAL_TABLE_SIZE_MB AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS PERCENT_TABLE_SIZE,
       CAST(100.0 * SUM(TABLE_SIZE_MB / TOTAL_TABLE_SIZE_MB) OVER(ORDER BY N DESC) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS RUNNING_PERCENT_SIZE
FROM   T
ORDER  BY 3 desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this script to find all table size:

```
SELECT
    table_schema || '.' || table_name AS TableName,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"')) AS TableSize
FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY
    pg_total_relation_size('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') DESC
```

For other different script to find size in PostgreSQL, Please visit this url:
http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/05/how-to-find-size-of-database-and-table-in-postgresql/