# Refresh materialized views with concurrency

Tags: postgresql, indexing, materialized-views

I have a PostgreSQL DB, where I use materialized views. 
The problem occurs when I try to refresh these materialized views.

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW product_cat_mview;
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW productsforproject;
```

My solution is, when the user want to see updated data, he should click a "refresh button" on the web page, but this takes about 50s (on a local connection and about 2 minutes from the application server) and all this time the user has to wait, which is not good.

Now I should create a solution to automatically refresh these materialized views every 10 minutes.
I have created a Java solution with multithreading. But I have one problem.

The first query

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY product_cat_mview;
```

works correct, but the second

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY productsforproject;
```

complains that I need to create a unique index. I tried create index, unique index etc. that I found in google, but I still get the message to "Create unique index".

Comment: Does this error get raised when you run the refreshes one by one?

Comment: I run them one by one with delay of 30 seconds.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You will have to create a unique index on the materialized view itself.

This would look like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON productsforproject (id);
```

Replace `id` with a suitable unique key column or a (comma separated) combination of such columns.

The reason for this requirement is that a concurrent refresh works different from a normal refresh: the query is executed, and the existing rows in the materialized view are updated or deleted or new rows inserted based on the query result.  [The unique index is required](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) to identify which row in the materialized view should be updated or deleted.

Comment: I have created this index. "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON productsforproject (barcode, materialdescription ASC);"  But I have message : ERROR: cannot refresh materialized view "public.productsforproject" concurrently
  Hint: Create a unique index with no WHERE clause on one or more columns of the materialized view.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the correct schema, like `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON public.productsforproject ...`. Or you created it in the wrong database by mistake.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added a unique index but when I try to refresh concurrently and query the materialized view - the query is stuck until the refresh ends. any idea?

Comment: Did you use `CONCURRENTLY`? Maybe open your own question for that and show the query, its execution plan and the contents of `pg_locks` while the refresh is running.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: If I undersand the refresh concurrency mechanism correctly, the data is recovered into a temporary table then old and new table are switched. Why is it necessary to create a unique index?

Comment: @FabriceChapuis That's not what happens with a concurrent refresh. The data in the materialized view are actually updated with the query results; hence the unique index.

Comment: @EugenKonkov I have added an explanation.