# Error 55000 `object_not_in_prerequisite_state` when trying to refresh a materialized view

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY recipe_search;`, but PostgreSQL gives me this error: `ERROR 55000 (object_not_in_prerequisite_state): cannot refresh materialized view "public.recipe_search" concurrently`.

The materialized view in question looks like this in `psql`:

```
# \d recipe_search

   Materialized view "public.recipe_search"
  Column  |          Type          | Modifiers
----------+------------------------+-----------
 id       | integer                |
 title    | character varying(255) |
 document | tsvector               |
Indexes:
    "recipe_search_document_index" gin (document)
    "recipe_search_title_trgm_index" gin (title gin_trgm_ops)
```

Why can't I refresh this concurrently?

Comment: Somebody just downvoted this. If you're mad that I answered my own question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.
When I ran into this problem, I searched the web for this error message and found no helpful information. After I solved the problem, I came here to document it so that future searchers will find it. This fits exactly with the mission of StackOverflow.

Comment: Self-answered questions are okay, but the fact that you self-answer it doesn't affect the question quality. Your question lacks the information needed to reproduce the problem. Aside from that, searching for the error message gives me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803781/refresh-materialized-views-with-concurrency, which this looks a dupe of, and a comment there suggests the error message should have been followed by a hint, which is not present in your question. (No, I didn't vote, at least not yet. The idea of posting it here is indeed good.)

Comment: @hvd I hadn't seen the hint because I was running the `REFRESH` via a trigger and a db library - if I try the `REFRESH` via psql directly, I do see it. I probably should have added the `\d` of the view; I've updated the question accordingly. But the main thing I wanted to accomplish was to enable searches for this error message to find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The materialized view needs a unique index

A materialized view cannot be refreshed `CONCURRENTLY` unless it has at least one unique index, as described in the docs:

> CONCURRENTLY
>
> ... This option is only allowed if there is at least one UNIQUE index on the materialized view which uses only column names and includes all rows; that is, it must not index on any expressions nor include a WHERE clause.
>
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html