# What's the difference between pg_table_size, pg_relation_size & pg_total_relation_size? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

What's the difference between `pg_table_size()`, `pg_relation_size()` & `pg_total_relation_size()`?

I understand the basic differences explained [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE), but what does it imply in terms of how much space my table is actually using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596624/how-do-you-find-the-disk-size-of-a-postgres-postgresql-table-and-its-indexes/2596678#2596678

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm mostly confused about "returns the on-disk size in bytes of one fork of that relation." What's a relation & a fork in this context? (I'm new to PostgreSQL) It also lists some fork examples: "main data fork", "Free Space Map", "Visibility Map" & "initialization fork". What are those? Which one is relevant to the actual disk space my table is using?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For a random table:

```
# select 
  pg_relation_size(20306, 'main') as main,
  pg_relation_size(20306, 'fsm') as fsm,
  pg_relation_size(20306, 'vm') as vm,
  pg_relation_size(20306, 'init') as init,
  pg_table_size(20306), 
  pg_indexes_size(20306) as indexes,
  pg_total_relation_size(20306) as total;
  main  |  fsm  |  vm  | init | pg_table_size | indexes |  total 
--------+-------+------+------+---------------+---------+--------
 253952 | 24576 | 8192 |    0 |        286720 |  196608 | 483328
(1 row)
```

From that, you can tell `pg_table_size` is the sum of all the return values of `pg_relation_size`. And `pg_total_relation_size` is the sum of `pg_table_size` and `pg_indexes_size`.

If you want to know how much space your tables are using, use `pg_table_size` and `pg_total_relation_size` to think about them -- one number is table-only, and one number is table + indexes.

Check the [storage file layout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html) for some info about what `fsm`, `vm`, and `init` mean, and how they're stored on disk.

Answer (score 58):

I am pretty sure after looking into the below image you will get a good understanding of various size relationships. I have made this diagram after reading all the answers mentioned in this answer section & analyzing more in DB for the query.

For storage file layout fsm, vm, and init mean, you can get from this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html) like @jmelesky mentioned.

[image: types of memory in postgresql]

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. Then it seems that TOAST size can be computed as `pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid) - pg_indexes_size(relid)`

Comment: @EM0 that's right

Comment: Ran across this as I'm putting together metrics for a Postgresql db. The docs state that given 1 argument (ie the relation), pg_relation_size will return the main fork only. So @EM0's calculation will still include the fms, vm, and init as well as the TOAST size. As of v14 there appears to be no way to get the combined main, fsm, vm, and init forks (relation_size in the diagram) as one method call.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT

Comment: Got your point. Then toast_size = pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_indexes_size(relid) - (pg_relation_size(relid, 'main') + pg_relation_size(relid, 'fsm') + pg_relation_size(relid, 'vm') + pg_relation_size(relid, 'init')) 
 
<OR>

toast_size = pg_table_size(relid)  - ((pg_relation_size(relid, 'main') + pg_relation_size(relid, 'fsm') + pg_relation_size(relid, 'vm') + pg_relation_size(relid, 'init)'))

Comment: Small errata in the image: the bottom box says "total_relational_size", should be "total_relation_size"

Answer (score 14):

`pg_table_size`: Disk space used by the specified table, excluding indexes (but including TOAST, free space map, and visibility map)

`pg_relation_size`: The size of the main data fork of the relation

```
select
      pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) as total_size,
      pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid, 'main')) as relation_size_main,
      pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid, 'fsm')) as relation_size_fsm,
      pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid, 'vm')) as relation_size_vm,
      pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid, 'init')) as relation_size_init,
      pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(relid)) as table_size,
      pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) as external_size
 from 
      pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables
where 
      schemaname = 'XXXX'
  and relname like 'XXXXXX';
```

```
total_size         | 6946 MB
relation_size_main | 953 MB
relation_size_fsm  | 256 kB
relation_size_vm   | 32 kB
relation_size_init | 0 bytes
table_size         | 6701 MB
external_size      | 5994 MB
```

so pg_table_size is not only the sum of all the return values of pg_relation_size but you have to add toast size

```
toast_bytes         | 5748 MB
```

Comment: what do you mean by external size ?

Comment: total_size - total table size
data_size - size of table's rows
external_size - size of external elements, such as indexes etc.

Comment: "A table that has columns with potentially large entries will have an associated TOAST table, which is used for out-of-line storage of field values that are too large to keep in the table rows proper."  -  from the postgres docs.

Comment: @Dineshkumar you can look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70397779/8609847