# What's the relation between pg_table_size and pg_relation_size?

Tags: postgresql

After executing the query provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991380/whats-the-difference-between-pg-table-size-pg-relation-size-pg-total-relatio), I got below result

```
Select  pg_relation_size(20473, 'main'),pg_relation_size(20473,'fsm'),
pg_relation_size(20473,'vm'),pg_relation_size(20473,'init'),pg_table_size(20473)
from pg_statio_user_tables
```

[image].

Why am I not getting

```
pg_relation_size(20473,'main') + pg_relation_size(20473,'fsm') + pg_relation_size(20473,'vm') + pg_relation_size(20473,'init') = pg_table_size(20473)?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_relation_size` calls `calclulate_relation_size`.

`pg_table_size` calls `calculate_table_size`.

`calculate_table_size` calls `calclulate_relation_size` and `calculate_toast_table_size`.

So when calling `pg_table_size` the `TOAST`-Data is added.

[Link to Source Code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/dbsize.c)

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE):

> `pg_relation_size(relation regclass, fork text)`
> Disk space used by the specified fork (`'main'`, `'fsm'`, `'vm'`, or `'init'`) of the specified table or index
>
> `pg_table_size(regclass)`
> Disk space used by the specified table, excluding indexes (but including TOAST, free space map, and visibility map)

So it must be the [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) table.