# Postgresql database and table size

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

this is my current table size:

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('items'));

 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
210 GB
```

but when I using pg_databse_size, it shows 1901GB

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty (pg_database_size ('mydb'));

 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 1901 GB
(1 row)
```

I have been checking all tables, and the items table is the biggest.

My questions is: how to make me understand this situation? Could you explain to me about this condition? Or give me a link to make me understand it.

Comment: What are you asking ? The Db size is clearly bigger than a table ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/functions-admin.html

Comment: @Mokadillion, my question is: I have 100 tables and all 99 tables only has arround 90GB, and items table has 210GB, but when I did checking the database size, it shows 1901GB. why it could be happen? and how to check where is the 1901- 300GB ( items and others tables) ?

Comment: database size will likely be the size of the entire cluster, not just the objects in your database, so everything in the /data/ directory

Comment: `pg_relation_size()` doesn't take indexes into account, `pg_database_size()` does

Comment: I got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991566/3728442 .thanks all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between pg\_table\_size, pg\_relation\_size & pg\_total\_relation\_size? (PostgreSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991380/whats-the-difference-between-pg-table-size-pg-relation-size-pg-total-relatio)