# Extracted CSV/txt file is bigger than total table size

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We have table "table1" containing 100000 rows, which includes blob data. The total table size is 3.5 GB.

When tried to extract all records into CSV/.txt file by using `copy` or `\o` commands the generated output file is 100 GB in size.

ex:

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('table1));
    3.5 GB
```

Please let us know how this actually generated this much huge size and how will get know the actual table size?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991380/whats-the-difference-between-pg-table-size-pg-relation-size-pg-total-relatio

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blob data", and how exactly did you export the data?

Comment: Assuming your "blob data" is a `bytea`, then this could be explained by Postgres compression of those values. Also `bytea` will be hex encoded in the output, meaning a single byte will be converted to two characters