# How to find a breakdown of db size to identify the high space consumer - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the size of my database

I tried the below codes

**option 1**

```
select t1.datname AS db_name,  
       pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(t1.datname)) as db_size
from pg_database t1
order by pg_database_size(t1.datname) desc;
```

**option 2**

```
\l+
```

Both the option return an output of ~2500 GB for `db1`. But the fact is our data (for db1) is only around 50 GB.

This size of 2500 gb seems impossible (based on my knowledge).

Can you guys help me understand whether table definitions, index setup etc and all can take up so much space?

Is there anyway to find out which one is causing/consuming a such huge space? I would like to know the breakdown of db1. So, I can find out which part of db1 is consuming so much space. Ideally the data for db1 is only 40-50 gb.

**option 1 output**

```
"db1"   "2533 GB"
"dreAm" "23 GB"
"db2"   "23 GB"
"db3"   "20 MB"
"postgres"  "7481 kB"
"template1" "7481 kB"
"template0" "7473 kB"
```

**option 2 output**

```
  Name    |    Owner    | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |      Access privileges      |  Size   | Tablespace |                Description
-----------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 db2       | test2       | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =Tc/dc                     +| 23 GB   | pg_default |
           |             |          |            |            | dc=CTc/dc                  +|         |            |
           |             |          |            |            | webapi_sa=c/dc              |         |            |
 db3       | dream       | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |                             | 23 GB   | pg_default |
 db1       | test1       | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =Tc/kt                     +| 2533 GB | pg_default |
           |             |          |            |            | ktph=CTc/kt                +|         |            |
           |             |          |            |            | webapi_sa=c/ktph           +|         |            |
           |             |          |            |            | za=c/kt                     |         |            |
 test      | test_admin  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =Tc/test_admin             +| 20 MB   | pg_default | test database
           |             |          |            |            | test_admin=CTc/test_admin+  |         |            |
           |             |          |            |            | test_app=Tc/test_admin      |         |            |
 postgres  | postgres    | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |                             | 7481 kB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 template0 | postgres    | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres                +| 7473 kB | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
           |             |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres       |         |            |
 template1 | postgres    | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres                +| 7481 kB | pg_default | default template for new databases
```

While I found the schema under which occupies the largest memory, I am not able to list the size of tables under that schema using below code

```
select table_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'results'
order by pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name));
```

When I do the above, I get an error message `ERROR:  relation "metadata" does not exist SQL state: 42P01`

But we do have `metadata` table in our database. However, it is empty. May I know why does this happen? Is there any other way to find the size of tables under each schema?

Comment: Is the schema `results`  in your `search_path`? If not, you need to use `format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name)` instead of only the table name as you do with with `quote_ident(table_name)`

Comment: @Laurenz Albe As far as I know, we only have 30-45 gb of data. But I am not sure whether any one else load the data. I would like to investigate it. How can I find out which table has more data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One or more of your tables are bloated.

Connect to the database and find your largest objects:

```
SELECT oid::regclass,
       pg_table_size(oid) AS size
FROM pg_class
ORDER BY size DESC;
```

This includes the TOAST table size.

Once you have found your candidate, use `pgstattuple` to confirm bloat:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple;
\x
SELECT * FROM pgstattuple_approx('bloated_table');
```

Fix the problem with `VACUUM (FULL)` and investigate and fix the cause.

Comment: Good answer, but it's important to use `pg_total_relation_size` rather than `pg_table_size` to get the full size of the tables including indexes - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991566/12663