# Postgresql size of tables (bytes) based on a column in the table

Tags: postgresql

Basically i want to be able to get the size of a table in bytes used by a particular user.

I have a  **user**  table and i have the  **id**  of this table in every other table in the database.
This code gets me the size in bytes of all tables in the database.

```
SELECT relname as "Table", pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size" FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

But i want to add a  **where**  clause to get only for a particular  **user id**  in the tables.

**EDITED:**
The possible duplicate answers only half of my question. I basically want a more specific size based on a column present in every table.

Something like this.
    SELECT relname as "Table", pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size" FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables  **WHERE "table_name"."user_id" = 1**  ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;

Comment: Have you checked [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596624/how-do-you-find-the-disk-size-of-a-postgres-postgresql-table-and-its-indexes) and [this page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage)?

Comment: @EmanueleGiona I forgot to mention that i have already checked the question and the page and unfortunately i get the same output as the above mentioned code. I wanted to know if it is possible to get the size used by a particular **user** by his **id** something like a `WHERE "table_name"."user_id" = 1`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes it answers only half my query. I need a little more specific size of table data used by a particular **user** based on his **id**.

Comment: This is a guess: Unless you have partitioned tables I think the answer is no. I would recommend you to ask it on http://dba.stackexchange.com though

Comment: @JorgeCampos thank you for your response and recommendation.